# startx in framebuffer using pythons subprocess.call

Tags: python, debian, subprocess, raspbian, framebuffer

I have a python program that needs to run

> FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0 startx -- :1

It is important that it runs the "-- :1" variable so that it can run console1 on fb0.

I have tried a few different variations including:

- **subprocess.call("FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0 startx -- :1", shell=True);**

  - Starts but doesn't use console1
  - Changes ownership of /home/pi/.Xauthority file so next boot fails.
- **subprocess.call(["FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0", "startx", "-- :1"]);**

  - fails.
- **subprocess.call(["FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0", "startx -- :1"]);**

  - fails.
- **subprocess.call(["FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0 startx", "-- :1"]);**

  - fails.
- **os.system("FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0 startx -- :1");**

  - Starts but doesn't use console1
  - Changes ownership of /home/pi/.Xauthority file so next boot fails.

I have tried running the python program with and without sudo privileges and it didn't help.

I can't find a proper way to get this command running properly.
Basically, I want the python program to start the gui interface with this specific console.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)?

Comment: it doesn't look like python issue. The first code example is correct. It is the same as if you run `sh -c 'FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0 startx -- :1'` in the shell. Make sure that the command works in your shell.

Comment: I realised my issue was that I was running the python script as root... it worked after I stopped doing that. 
Thanks for the help!